# Responding to specific dialled phone number on ios/xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, callkit

Ideally, we would like to start our Xamarin ios app(or pop to foreground) when the user is calling a specific phone number(when connected).

My question is, can we get the dialled phone number? 
If I understand it correctly, CallKit will give me en event to hook up to, even for non voip-calls, but looks like it is quite limited what info I am getting from the CXCallUpdate object?

From what I understand, bringing our own app to the foreground is not possible, so a notification which the user could click to bring the app to the foreground could also do the trick.

Comment: You cannot get any details of calls. It is a privacy restriction.

Comment: Did your problem has been solved?

Comment: No, I just accepted that this is not possible to acheive :)